# Understanding the basics of the conjugacy problem better

Tags: group-theory, decision-problems

There are classes of group presentations for which the conjugacy problem is known to be soluble, for example braid groups.

Is the word “soluble” here a synonym for “decidable”?

Of the groups in the soluble class, is there a particular group that is particularly simple to see why it is soluble?

Do the groups in the soluble class share a feature that causes them to be soluble?

Of Dehn’s three most important decision problems I can understand why the word problem is elementary and important (testing within a group for equality of two elements) and likewise the isomorphism problem (testing between groups for equality of themselves).

Because the word problem is a special case of the conjugacy problem it is more general and more difficult. Is this the logic behind why the conjugacy problem is also one of the three fundamental decision problems? Are there other candidates of decision problem that could be considered fundamental in group theory, or is this not a good question in some way?

Comment: Yes, soluble means decidable in this context. Examples  of classes of groups in which it is particularly easy to see that the conjugacy problem is soluble are finite groups and free groups.

Comment: In the literature the word “soluble” seems to be used maybe more than decidable, or at least fairly often? Is there a reason for this, since (speaking as a beginner) the word “decidable” seems preferable. I will look at the free group in terms of conjugacy, had already been thinking it is important to understand this group well.

Comment: Decidable is the formal term used by logicians. Mathematicians are inclined to say soluble (or solvable) meaning can be solved. I agree that it is preferable to use decidable, but you can't change the way people speak! Even worse, people sometimes write "We can solve this problem" meaning "This problem is decidable". To me "we can solve" suggests that we really can solve it in practice rather than there just existing an algorithm to solve it, which is a weaker statement.

Comment: Reassuringly logicians decided upon the more logical word. Thanks for the reminder that solvable is also used to mean soluble.

Comment: Solving equations in a group is a more general decision problem, as the conjugacy problem can be phrased as "does $X^{-1}gX=h$ admit any solutions?".

Comment: Oh, and I meant to say: understanding equations in groups is also pretty fundamental, but also much harder. For example, understanding equations in free groups is the first major step in the proof of an old question of Tarski on the first order theory of free groups, while understanding equations in hyperbolic groups is one of the key components in solving the isomorphism problem for hyperbolic groups.

Comment: @user1729 Does solving equations in a group often involve the unknowns being within pre-specified subgroups, that is subgroup-restricted? The decomposition problem, which could be viewed as a generalisation of the conjugacy problem, is subgroup-restricted.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have always thought that "decidable" is about decision problems (e.g. "are $g$ and $h$ conjugate?") while "soluble"/"solvable" is a more general term about algorithmic problems where the output is more than yes/no (e.g. "does there exist an algorithm to find some $x\in G$ such that $x^{-1}gx=h$?"). Is this approximately correct, or is decidable used in both contexts?

Comment: @SingleMalt No, equations with constraints is a more general topic.

Comment: @user1729 Yes you are right about "decidable" - that is a formal concept that refers to decision problems. I think "solvable" is less formal. With the conjugacy problem, perhaps "solvable" implies that we can find a conjugating element (known as a "witness"), which the answer is yes, although typically you could always do that by exhaustive search. In my original comment I just said that decidable is the same as solvable for the conjugacy problem, but perhaps not in general.

Comment: Decidable can also be a confusing concept. If I have understood things correctly (which is not guaranteed!) then the statement "every even  integer $n \ge 4$ is the sum of two primes" is decidable, because it is decided either by the algorithm that prints "yes" or by the algorithm that prints "no". So an algorithm to solve it exists - the fact that we do not know which of these is the correct algorithm is irrelevant!